# Limit Flutter Draggable widget to a box

Tags: flutter, scrollbar, draggable

I am using the Flutter **Draggable** widget (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Draggable-class.html) to create a sort of special scrollbar, Draggable has an `axis` property so one can limit it to just vertical axis, but how can I limit it to its parent area, not further?

Check the attached image, I want to limit the movement of the black bar to cyan area (the parent container of Draggable):

[image]

Comment: you should not use `Draggable` if you want to create sort of custom vertical slider - use a `GestureDetector` instead and place your "thumb" accordingly

Comment: great, worked, please post this as answer so other developers can use it.

Comment: post a self-answer with your code then - i just gave a suggestion, not a real code

Comment: btw some time ago i wrote a similar [gist](https://gist.github.com/pskink/9473bff3b37d171332a0aeaedfef5bd8) with some "animated" stuff that can be applied when releasing the finger so that it mimics "inertia" effect - all done with `AnimationController`